# I am facing the following error while upgrading to jboss wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly-8

```
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.LinkageError cannot be cast to java.lang.Exception
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:473)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:81)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.jsp.JspFileHandler.handleRequest(JspFileHandler.java:32)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.server.handlers.MetricsHandler.handleRequest(MetricsHandler.java:64)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.core.MetricsChainHandler.handleRequest(MetricsChainHandler.java:59)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:251)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:186)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:227)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImplSetup(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:149)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:111)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:722)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:695)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:846)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:818)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,997 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.apache.jsp.JSP.ControlPanelHelper_jsp._jspService(ControlPanelHelper_jsp.java:1329)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:81)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.jsp.JspFileHandler.handleRequest(JspFileHandler.java:32)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.server.handlers.MetricsHandler.handleRequest(MetricsHandler.java:64)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.core.MetricsChainHandler.handleRequest(MetricsChainHandler.java:59)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:251)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:186)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:227)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImplSetup(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:149)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:111)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at emapservlet.ControllerServlet.displayNextPage(ControllerServlet.java:173)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at emapservlet.ControllerServlet.Process(ControllerServlet.java:89)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at emapservlet.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:55)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:523)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.server.handlers.MetricsHandler.handleRequest(MetricsHandler.java:64)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.core.MetricsChainHandler.handleRequest(MetricsChainHandler.java:59)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,998 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,999 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,999 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,999 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,999 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,999 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,999 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,999 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,999 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
2022-03-01 01:31:49,999 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please don't just post your log. Share your code, ask a question. How is anyone supposed to help you with this little information (and effort)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a lot that we can say about this error.

It appears that there is a bug in `org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service`.  It is assuming that every exception is an `Exception`.  In this case the exception is an `Error` so a cast is failing.

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/LinkageError.html) for `java.lang.LinkageError` says that it is caused by binary compatibility problem.  That implies you have inconsistent versions of ... something.  But >>this<< stacktrace doesn't give any real clues as to where that problem is.

You need to look at the rest of the logs to try and find the stacktrace for the `LinkageError`.

Comment: Thank you , my concern is the same where i cannot trace where exactly the problem is, and it is a very large application

Comment: Well ... unless you give us more information, I'm afraid we can't help you.

Comment: we are trying to upgrade the version of java using wildfly, one of the jsp page is not loading (its rendering) but work fine with previous version and local too, there is no change with the code

Comment: Like I said.  You have incompatible versions of something.  But we can't tell you what is incompatible with what from the information you provided.